# How to filter attachments view depending on the records in odoo

Tags: xml, odoo-9

Currently I am developing a customer service management module in `odoo`.

In this one users can create cases. Cases contain attachments. I have a button on cases form view, clicking on it will open attachment view (ir.attachment).

What I want is to filter attached documents based on records; i.e, when clicking on one record, its associated attachment should only view.

My code is as follows..

```
<button class="oe_stat_button" name="%(csm.attachement_action)d" string="Documents" type="action" />

<record id="attachement_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Attachments</field>
            <field name="res_model">ir.attachment</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>
            <field name="domain" eval="[('res_id','=',active_id)]" />
            <field name="view_id" ref="attachment_kanban"/>
            <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">To add attachments click on create</p>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the button call an action with a domain containing this

```
('res_id','=',active_id)
```

`res_id` keeps track of the "related resource".

Example of [action](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/stock/product_view.xml#L38) and [button](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/stock/product_view.xml#L161).

Or you can define a method that return an action and call it from the button, something like:

```
@api.multi
def open_related_attachments(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    domain = [
        ('res_id', '=', self.id),
    ]
    return {
        'name': 'Related attachments',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_model': 'ir.attachment',
        'target': 'current',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'tree,form',
        'domain': domain,
    }
```

Comment: You mean adding a domain_force in action window?

Comment: nope, define a window action with a simple domain and call the action from the button using notation like `name="%(my_action)d`

Comment: examples... action: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/stock/product_view.xml#L38 and buttons: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/stock/product_view.xml#L161

Comment: I tried adding that. But it is giving error as active_id' is not defined. I have updated my code

Comment: weird, I updated the answer w/ another solution that works for sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112691/discussion-between-akhil-mathew-and-simahawk).

Answer (score 0):

Attach the context on button:

```
<button class="oe_stat_button" name="%(csm.attachement_action)d" string="Documents" type="action" context="{'res_name': name}"/>
```

And filter it on the domain field:

```
 <field name="domain">[('res_model','=','your.model'),('res_id','=', active_id),('res_name', '=', res_name + '...')]</field>
```